# Find the number of days passed since January 1 of a particular year in vba

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I want to find the number of days passed since January 1 from a date I provide.

Example :

```
Input - 12/01/2015
Output - 12

Input - 02/02/2015
Output - 33
```

I need the shortest possible way to do this. Please tell me if there is any function available in vb for this.

Comment: subtract 01/01/extract(year) from your date

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:  (input in cell C4 .. or replace C4 with your input)

```
=C4-DATE(YEAR(C4)-1,12,31)
```

(I looked at DAYS360() first, but that one isn't the same math OP needs, so not a good choice there)

and yeah, no vba needed .. I'd just stick with a normal formula if you can ;)
VBA can be a bit slower sometimes, and harder to maintain ...

Comment: Good answer, although note that this will fail if year is 1900.

Comment: lol, fair point .. Exel wraps 1899 around to 3799 .. O.o  How silly .. shouldn't be too much of a problem depending on what OP needs this for ... but thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0):

`DatePart("y", dt)` is one way, and possibly the shortest, where `dt` is your date.

Alternatively, you can use `=A1 - DATE(YEAR(A1), 1, 0)` directly on a worksheet, where `A1` holds a date.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, just subtract the dates:

```
intDays = dt1 - #1/1/2015#    ' Date literals use #
```

Dates are stored internally in VBA as `Double`, with "days" as the integer portion and "time" as the decimal portion. You can always just subtract one from another to determine the difference in number of days.