# How can I find the time number of days between a given date, and the given date's first day of the year in VBA?

Tags: vba

For example, the inputted date is 2001/01/21 the output must be 21 because 21 days passed since the inputted date's first day of the year.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268926/find-the-number-of-days-passed-since-january-1-of-a-particular-year-in-vba

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to do it!!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste the following to your VB Editor. Then, run the "TestNumberOfDays" procedure.

```
Function FirstDayOfTheGivenYear(pDate As Date)
'this will return first day of the given year
FirstDayOfTheGivenYear = 1 * (CDate(pDate) - DatePart("y", CDate(pDate) - 1))
End Function

Function YTDDays(pDate As Date) As Long
'this will find the day differences between two dates
YTDDays = DateDiff("d", FirstDayOfTheGivenYear(pDate), pDate) + 1
End Function

Sub TestNumberOfDays()
'change the date according to your need
MsgBox (YTDDays("2001/01/30"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform the date to a value and do the same for the "new" date? Do the same in Dev.mode newCelldate.Value - yearStartdate.Value?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
InputDate = #2001/01/21#
OrdinalDay = DatePart("y", InputDate)
```